# Are plists the best way to store multiple in-app preferences for my iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, plist

I'm diving into iOS development and am building a game that has multiple game types.  When the user selects which game type they want to play, they are presented with a game configuration screen where they can adjust their options for how the game will play.  Since there are two different game types, there will be two different configuration screens.  With my limited knowledge on iOS programming, I was planning to use two separate plists to present the options and store the settings.  Would anyone suggest a better way to do this?

Thanks so much in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's an actual application preference, you can use NSUserDefaults to save the information to the standard defaults. That way you don't have to mess with files.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty much decent approach. Although you can use single plist file with dictionary which has two keys (one for each game).